# How to pass method argument to class property?

Tags: php, oop, function

I am trying to create properties based on the method arguments. For example:

```
class Test{

   public function newProperty($prop1,$prop2){

   //I want to create $this->argu1 and $this->argu2 after calling newProperty method. 

  }
}


$test=new Test();
$test->newProperty('argu1','argu2')
```

Is this possible? Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as simple as:

```
$this->$prop1 = 'whatever';
```

suppose you wanted to handle an undefined number of arguments, you could use:

```
foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
  $this->$arg = 'some init value';
}
```

On the other hand, all this is quite unnecessary as all these properties will be *public* and thus:

```
$test->argu1 = 'whatever';
```

would do exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Test{

    private argu1 = '';
    private argu2 = '';

    public function newProperty($argu1,$argu2){
        //This is a great place to check if the values supplied fit any rules.
        //If they are out of bounds, set a more appropriate value.

        $this->prop1 = $argu1;
        $this->prop2 = $argu2;

    }
}
```

I'm a little unclear from the question if the class properties should be named $prop or $argu.  Please let me know if I have them backwards.

Comment: Ty @Surreal. Yoshi answer is closer to what I need. I need. +1 though